# Click enter key for submit

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I am having problems entering an event. I have read multiple post's regarding this issue, but have yet to find a solution.
The project must work in Chrome, FF & IE (8,9,10,11). It is not working in any browser at the current moment.

I have two form's Register/login on one page

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlRegister" runat="server"BorderWidth="0">
     <table class="register">
          <tr align="left">
               <td class="row_left_heading" colspan="2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="textbox_required"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td class="row_left">
        Last name
                </td>
                <td class="row_right">
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" CssClass="textbox_required"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
           </tr>
```

...................................
There more filed for enter data and validation filed
...................................

```
-Register button

<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ValidationGroup="group_registration" 
  ID="btnRegister" CssClass="btnDownload"      
  ImageUrl="../images/download_now_blue_clear.png" 
  OnClick="btnRegister_Click" />
```

On right side of page, There's the login element

```
<tr align="left">
     <td class="row_left">
          Email
     </td>
     <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"
             CssClass="textbox_required"></asp:TextBox>
     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td class="row_left">
           Password
     </td>
     <td>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"
               CssClass="textbox_required" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox><br />
     </td>
 </tr>
```

... And login Button

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ValidationGroup="group_login"
    ImageUrl="/forum/forum_images/button_login.png"
    ID="btnLogin" OnClick="btnLogin_Click"
    />
```

Above is the form for input data and everything is working fine when clicked via the mouse button.

Code for enter button:

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Sets up javascript events that handle posting data using enter key
    /// </summary>
    private void SetupJSEventHandlers()
    {
        txtUserName.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "SetActiveForm('login');");
        txtUserName.Attributes.Add("onblur", "DeactivateForm();");

        txtPassword.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "SetActiveForm('login');");
        txtPassword.Attributes.Add("onblur", "DeactivateForm();");

        txtFirstName.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "SetActiveForm('register');");
        txtFirstName.Attributes.Add("onblur", "DeactivateForm();");

        txtPhone.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "SetActiveForm('register');");
        txtPhone.Attributes.Add("onblur", "DeactivateForm();");

        txtEmail.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "SetActiveForm('register');");
        txtEmail.Attributes.Add("onblur", "DeactivateForm();");
    }
```

And catch:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ......
            SetupJSEventHandlers();
        }
        else
        {
            if (Request[ACTIVE_FORM_NAME] == "register")
            {
                btnRegister_Click(null, null);
            }
            else if (Request[ACTIVE_FORM_NAME] == "login")
            {
                btnLogin_Click(null, null);
            }
    txtFirstName.Focus();
    }
```

Another Snippet of code I have tried (And failed with):

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
          {
               if (Request[ACTIVE_FORM_NAME] == "register")
          {
               btnRegister_Click(null, null);
          }
          else if (Request[ACTIVE_FORM_NAME] == "login")
          {
                btnLogin_Click(null, null);
          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Modify your question title and make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using `DefaultButton` property of a Panel or a form. You can set different `DefaultButton` to different panel.

```
 <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlRegister" DefaultButton="btnRegister">
```

Comment: It's ok when i have one form but if I have two forms with same default button i come back to same problem

Comment: If its different form, you can change the ID of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You're recreating a lot of built-in ASP.NET functionality here. You should remove your event handlers and the `ACTIVE_FORM_NAME` property.

Instead, put each of the "forms" into separate `<asp:Panel>` elements.

The `<asp:Panel>` element has a property called `DefaultButton`. Set each of these to the relevant `<asp:Button>` IDs.

ASP.NET will then handle the client-side work of catching the enter key, and your relevant `btnX_Click()` event handlers will automatically be called.

Answer (score 0):

Use DefaultButton option in Panel

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlRegister" runat="server"BorderWidth="0" DefaultButton="btnRegister">
 Some Content
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlLogin" runat="server"BorderWidth="0" DefaultButton="btnLogin">
 Some Content
</asp:Panel>
```